# API call within a Promise (TypeError: response.json is not a function)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, httprequest, response

Why do I keep getting TypeError: response.json is not a function?

I did an extensive research about this, but all responses referred to async await calls, and I am curious about the pure Promise syntax (the "new Promise.." syntax by the way, not the one that uses Promise.all)

```
 const getName0 = (username) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`;
  const response = fetch(url);

  if (response) {
    const json = response.json();
    return resolve(json.name);

  } else {
    return reject("User does not exist!");

  }

});

getName0('rickitan').then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Did you fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this fetch syntax

```js
fetch('https://api-to-call.com/endpoint').then(response => {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Request failed!');
}, networkError => console.log(networkError.message)).then(jsonResponse => {
  return jsonResponse;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Your code works, however Im curious about the syntax that I used above. What's wrong with it?